# The Complex field is not ordered but is defined with ordered pairs?

Tags: complex-analysis

quick question:

The complex field is defined as the set of all ordered pairs (a,b) where a and b are real numbers. But the complex field is not an ordered field.

How can the complex field be defined by ordered pairs if it is not an ordered field?

Comment: How come you can't grow complex crop in the complex field?

Comment: @Saucy O'Path: Boo!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a contradiction. The word "ordered" in your question has two distinct meanings. In "ordered pair" it means that (for example) $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are different. In "ordered field" it means the relation "greater than" has the properties you expect - for example, squares should be greater than or equal to $0$.

It turns out that there is no way to decide when one ordered pair is larger than another that satisfies all the usual properties you expect about ordering "numbers".